# RSMB MQTT-SN & Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, mqtt, mosquitto

I've been told that MQTT-SN could work with bluetooth instead of TCP/IP.

I downloaded RSMB from http://git.eclipse.org/c/mosquitto/org.eclipse.mosquitto.rsmb.git

I tried then to configure it to work using anything other than TCP/IP without any luck. In fact the only thing I was able to configure using a configuration file was the port number because I could not find a list of possible configurations anywhere.

Does anybody know if it is possible to make such configuration (Bluetooth instead of TCP) in RSMB or any other MQTT broker????

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MQTT-SN support in RSMB is for MQTT-SN over UDP.

To use MQTT-SN over Bluetooth you will need to implement a Forwarder as described in section 5.5 of the [spec](http://mqtt.org/new/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/MQTT-SN_spec_v1.2.pdf) to bridge between a MQTT-SN gateway and a client on the Bluetooth device.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take at the specs!