# Mqtt Forwarder for bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, mqtt

I've been told that in order to connect devices through bluetooth, need to implement a Forwarder from [RSMB MQTT-SN & Bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483943/rsmb-mqtt-sn-bluetooth).

Btw, is there any more clearer way to state how to create a forwarder and how to connect through bluetooth for mqtt??

Answer (score 0):

The specification outlines what is needed to implement a MQTT-SN Gateway, it's probably the best documentation you are going to get.

But MQTT-SN is not the only solution depending on what you actually need to surface to a device via Bluetooth.

An example of making a single topic available as a Bluetooth LE GATT service can be found [here](https://github.com/hardillb/mqtt2ble) with some description [here](http://www.hardill.me.uk/wordpress/2015/07/28/building-bluetooth-le-devices/)